# Session timed out when POST/GET. Allow login, then post data

Tags: asp-classic

Classic asp.

Sometimes the session has timed out while the user has filled out a large form.

Currently the user just gets "you are not logged in", and the login-form.
When the user logs in again, (s)he have to start over, and navigate to the previous form to fill it out again.

I'd like to just submit the formdata again, if the user logs in successfully.

There a many forms/pages in the system, so the login-check is in a common include-file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is, in the header file included on all pages, if the user is logged out, create a form with all post and get values hidden, and the username/password field visible.

User then re-enters the username and password, and submits the form.

If the user is then succesfully logged in, the script continues and processes the data.

It will not work for uploads, but this is rarely used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Leif Session time is for Server to control the data keeping time , maybe you can use cookie for your issue because it is controlled by Client(Browser).  hopefully my idea can help you ,thanks willie

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP, our "One Way" posting code.

I set a cookie and save the cookie to the members table.

The cookie doesn't need to be anything fancy, date, name, IP, session works just fine. Encode them SHA256 with a Salt.

The idea is to use this special cookie if on a forms page and their user session has been lost or timed out.

Basic setup: (Not complete code just enough to get the idea and flow)
Login page. 
Create [SHA256](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2565) Hash

Save as Cookie

```
SetKeysCookie "CookieName","LostSession",strSHA256Hash,mysite.ext,"1"

Sub SetKeysCookie(strCookieName,strCookieKey,strCookieValue,strCookieDomain,strCookieExpires)
    Response.Cookies(strCookieName).Expires = DateAdd("d",strCookieExpires, Now())
    Response.Cookies(strCookieName).Domain = strCookieDomain
    Response.Cookies(strCookieName).Path = "/"
    Response.Cookies(strCookieName)(strCookieKey) = strCookieValue
    Response.Cookies(strCookieName).Secure = True
End Sub
```

Optional: I use the HTTP_Cookie which would be as follows.

```
Sub SetKeysCookieHttpOnly(strCookieName,strCookieKey,strCookieValue,strCookieDomain,strCookieExpires)
    strGMTDateRFC22 = CookieServerUTC("d","&strCookieExpires&",5,"GMT")  ' 1 Day set in char enc dec page
    Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", strCookieName & "=" & strCookieKey & "=" & strCookieValue & "; expires=" & strGMTDateRFC22 & "; domain="& strCookieDomain &"; path=/;"
End Sub
```

Update members database:

```
UPDATE Member SET LostSession='"&strSHA256Hash&"' WHERE ID = "&id&"" .....
```

On forms page: 
Check Session on Post... If Session = NULL then
Check if Cookie is set. 
Get the cookie 
Old method: Request.Cookies("CookieName")("LostSession")

New HTTP_Cookie

```
strCookieX = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE")
If InStr(strCookieX,"LostSession=") Then
    j = InStrRev(strCookieX, "LostSession=")
        if j > 0 Then
            strCookieTEMP = Mid(strCookieX, j+12)
        end if
        j = 64
        if j > 0 Then
            strCookieTEMP = Left(strCookieTEMP, j-0)
        End If
strCookie = strCookieTEMP
End If
```

The above will pull all your HTTP cookies and then search for your LostSession cookie. 
Because we know the fixed length we can pull it cleanly.

Next on the form we check to see which member this cookie is assigned to.

```
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 "
strSQL = strSQL & " ID,Email,ClientID,LostSession"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM Members "
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE LostSession = '"&strCookie&"' " 
    Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open strSQL,Conn,3,3
If rs.EOF=False Then
    Session("id") = rs("ID")
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

When found, we set the minimum Session Variables to allow this post to complete. 
Session("id") or Session("authorized") whatever you need to complete the post.

At the end of the post, as we successfully submitted the form we now can send the session failed user to the login page.

```
Session.Abandon

sRedirectPage = "https://domain.ext/logout.asp"
    Response.Status="403.6 IP Restricted"
    Response.AddHeader "Location",sRedirectPage
    Response.end
```

You should be able to see the different parts of the http cookie method of saving a session that has timed out.

If you need anything just ask.

Murray